# Sort a Map in ascending order based on frequency of occurance of n-grams

Tags: java

I am trying to sort the ngrams in the map in ascending order based on the frequency and then increment `rank` until it has reached `max`, in the method `getTopFile()`. 
The `getTop()` method is done by my lecturer, it is doing roughly the same thing but it uses a parameter `Language lang`.

My question is how can I sort the ngrams in the map in an ascending order by frequency of occurance?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Database {
    private Map<Integer, TextEntry> dbFile = new TreeMap<>();

    //Add file- Query
    public void addFile(CharSequence s) {
        System.out.println("in addFile() ");
        int ngram = s.hashCode();
//      Map<Integer, TextEntry> textDb = getTextEntries(ngram);
        Map<Integer, TextEntry> textDb = dbFile;

        int frequency = 1;
        if (textDb.containsKey(ngram)) {
            frequency += textDb.get(ngram).getFrequency();
        }
        textDb.put(ngram, new TextEntry(ngram, frequency));

    }

//  public void resizeFile(int max) {
//      System.out.println("in resizeFile() ");
//      Set<Integer> keys = dbFile.keySet();
//      for (Integer ngram : keys) {
//          Map<Integer, TextEntry> top = getTopFile(max, ngram);
//          dbFile.put(ngram, top);
//      }
//  }

    // Sort Language Map in ascending order
//  public Map<Integer, LanguageEntry> getTop(int max, Language lang) {
//      System.out.println("in getTop() ");
//      Map<Integer, LanguageEntry> temp = new TreeMap<>();
//      List<LanguageEntry> les = new ArrayList<>(db.get(lang).values());
//      Collections.sort(les);
//
//      int rank = 1;
//      for (LanguageEntry le : les) {
//          le.setRank(rank);
//          temp.put(le.getKmer(), le);
//          if (rank == max)
//              break;
//          rank++;
//      }
//      return temp;
//  }

    // Sort Map in ascending order
    public Map<Integer, TextEntry> getTopFile(int max, Integer ngram) {
        System.out.println("in getTopFile() ");
        Map<Integer, TextEntry> temp = new TreeMap<>();
        List<TextEntry> sortedList = dbFile.values()
                .stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(TextEntry::getFrequency))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        int rank = 1;
        for (TextEntry le : sortedList) {
            le.setRank(rank);
            temp.put(le.getKmer(), le);
            if (rank == max)
                break;
            rank++;
        }
        System.out.println(temp);
        return temp;
    }
```

```
public class TextEntry implements Comparable<TextEntry>  {
    private int kmer;
    private int frequency;
    private int rank;

    public TextEntry(int kmer, int frequency) {
        super();
        this.kmer = kmer;
        this.frequency = frequency;
    }

    public int getKmer() {
        return kmer;
    }

    public void setKmer(int kmer) {
        this.kmer = kmer;
    }

    public int getFrequency() {
        return frequency;
    }

    public void setFrequency(int frequency) {
        this.frequency = frequency;
    }

    public int getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public void setRank(int rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public int compareTo(TextEntry next) {
        return - Integer.compare(frequency, next.getFrequency());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + kmer + "/" + frequency + "/" + rank + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code you are having trouble with, and what *specific* problem do you have with it?

Comment: You forgot to ask an actual question.

Answer (score 0):

TreeMap sort elements by keys only. In your current implementation key has no information about frequency and thus cannot solve the problem. Technically it would be possible to use TextEntry as a key. But it is mutable (it has setters) and can be changed at any time without re-inserting (an thus without re-ordering), which would break sorting.

I'd suggest you to sort elements only then and there when and where you really need it.

To get a sorted list:

```
List<TextEntry> sortedList = dbFile.values()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(TextEntry::getFrequency))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

To find the max element:

```
TextEntry max = dbFile.values()
    .stream()
    .max(Comparator.comparing(TextEntry::getFrequency))
    .get();
```

Comment: I get an error "The method sorted(Comparator<? super Map<Integer,TextEntry>>) in the type Stream<Map<Integer,TextEntry>> is not applicable for the arguments (Comparator<TextEntry>)"

Comment: I suppose you wrote *dbFile.stream()* instead of *dbFile.values().stream()*.

Comment: I wrote dbFile.values().stream(), i edited the code above to what i entered

Comment: I overlooked that you have a map that contains other maps. Then what do you want to get sorted - the *dbFile* or elements in the each separate map in *dbFile*?

Comment: Oh my bad I am only meant to have one map not a map that contains other maps, ill try change this now

Comment: OK. Let us know when you have a new version :)

Comment: What I wrote regarding *sorted(...)* is applicable for your *nested* map, not for the *dbFile*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205240/discussion-between-mark-and-mentallurg).